# How to add default empty value in a combobox?

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a combo with all values coming from a OneToMany relationship.

I've made a custom form here `src/MySociety/Bundle/MyBundle/Form/Type/PersonRegistrationType.php`

This works well.

But I want to add another value *first* in that combo, which says something like "Choose something here".

What is the way to do this with Symfony?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take this exemple :

```
        ->add('channels', 'entity', array(
                        'class' => 'MyBundle:Channel',
                        'multiple'=> false,
                        'property'=> 'label',
                        'mapped'=>false,
                        'empty_value' => "Choose a Channel",
            ))
```

You can add 'empty-value'... I hope it will work with your need....